# How can make a decision based on multiple models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have three model project_site, project_manager and human_resource. each model has status Boolean attribute i want to print "approve" only if all status==true but want to print "reject" if any one of the status is set to false. each status has nil value by default.

```
        <% if project_site.human_resources.empty? %>
              <td class="pending fi-eye"><%= " Pending" %></td>
            <% elsif %>
              <% project_site.human_resources.each do |human_resource| %>
                <% if human_resource.status == false %>
                  <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                <% elsif human_resource.status == true %>
                  <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>

              <% elsif %>
                <% project_site.project_directors.each do |project_director| %>
                  <% if project_director.status == false %>
                    <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>

                <% elsif %>
                  <% project_site.project_managers.each do |project_manager| %>
                    <% if project_manager.status == false %>
                      <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: Take a look at how to write a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Is there any need for us to know the classes of your `td` tag and stuff like that ? Why do you have 4 different `ruby-on-rails` tags ?

Comment: You really should move the business logic into the model. The view should just be able to ask the model if its approved or not.

Comment: can i do this is view? if not then how can i solve this by putting logic in model??

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
is_approved = project_site.human_resources.all?{|e| e.status } # or .all?(&:status) will check if status true for all records
```

you can even simplify

```
all_approved = (project_site.project_managers +  project_site.human_resources + project_site.project_directors).all?(&:status)
```

it doesn't look perfect and I suggest to move it to the model.